# I want to copy files that do not have a number in their name

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel, cp

[image: These are all the files]

I want to use cp command using file globing to copy all those files that do not have a numeric value.

The copied files should not include 12a, ghf3 and s2d.

I tried using `cp [!0-9] *[!0-9] *[!0-9] destination/`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does the picture show? Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 8):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
cp -- ^*<->*(D^/) /path/to/destination/
```

Or `cp -- ^*[0-9]*(D^/) destination/`, `<->` matching any sequence of one or more ASCII decimal digits (a form of `<x-y>` where the bounds are not set).

(`^` being the negation operator, `D` to include hidden files, `^/` to also exclude the files of type directory which `cp` will refuse to copy without `-r`/`-R`/`-a` anyway).

Same with `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob failglob dotglob
cp -- !(*[0123456789]*) /path/to/destination/
```

`!(x)` (from ksh, requires `extglob` to be set at the time the code using it is read) as the equivalent of zsh's `^x`, `dotglob` as the equivalent of the `D` qualifier, bash has no equivalent for `^/`. Without `failglob`, that could copy the file called `!(*[0123456789]*)` literally if there was no matching file.

A POSIX version using globs is as always very painful to implement as there's no glob qualifier or equivalent of `nullglob`, `failglob` (default behaviour in zsh) or `globdot` / `dotglob` / `D` qualifier nor ksh-style or zsh-style negation operators:

```
set -- [*] *
[ "$1$2" = '[*]*' ] && shift
shift
set -- .[*] .* "$@"
[ "$1$2" = '.[*].*' ] && shift
shift
for file do
  case "$file" in
    (*[0123456789]* | . | ..) ;;
    (*) [ -d "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ] || set -- "$@" "$file";;
  esac
  shift
done
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && echo cp -- "$@" /path/to/destination/
```

But you could use `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '*[0-9]*' ! -type d \
  -exec sh -c 'exec cp "$@" /path/to/destination/' sh {} +
```

`LC_ALL=C` to work around the fact that `-name`'s `*` could fail to match on a sequence of bytes that cannot be decoded as text in the user's locale. In the `C` locale, `[0-9]` and `[0123456789]` are also equivalent. That means however that that could exclude file names that are encoded in charsets such as BIG5 or GB18030 where the encoding of some characters contain the byte values for the ASCII digits. Unlikely outside of China and dependencies.

`zsh` should be able to cope with locales and filenames using those charsets or file names that are not entirely made of text. `bash` as well though it switches to a byte-wise matching if the file names can't be fully decoded which can cause surprising results in some corner cases including the same as above with BIG5/GB18030.

`zsh`'s `[0-9]` is always the same as `[0123456789]`, bash's rarely so outside the C/POSIX locale.

---

Your:

> cp [!0-9] *[!0-9] *[!0-9] destination

Does not work because that's:

- `[!0-9]`: filename that is a single character other than those sorting between 0 and 9. And if there's no such single-letter character, in `bash` without `failglob` or `nullglob` enabled, that remains `[!0-9]` which is a file name that contains 2 digits.
- `*[!0-9]`: a filename that ends in a character other than those sorting between 0 and 9. So `1234567X` would match for instance.
- `*[!0-9]` same again which I guess is a typo, but if you meant `[!0-9]*` that would match `X12345` and if you meant `*[!0-9]*`, that would match `1234X5678`.

If you meant the equivalent of regexp `^[^0-9]*$`, or better `^[^0123456789]*$`  where `*` in regexp means 0 or more of *the preceding thing* instead of 0 or more *characters* in globs, then that would be `*([!0123456789])` in Korn-style extended globs (as also supported by bash with `extglob`)  or `[^0-9]#` in zsh extended globs. See also `+([!0123456789])` (ksh) and `[^0-9]##` (zsh) for the equivalent of ERE `+` (won't make a difference here as a filename cannot be empty anyway).

Also note that as you forgot the `--` to mark the end of options, any filename starting with `-` would have been treated as an option by `cp`. For instance, with a file named `-rt..`, with GNU `cp`, that would have ended up copy all other files and `/path/to/destination` recursively to the parent directory!

Answer (score 3):

A POSIX approach could be to save off the files that do contain a character sorting between 0 and 9 (with `[0-9]`; or decimal digit with `[[:digit:]]` or only the 0123456789 ones with `[0123456789]`), copy the remainder, and then restore the saved set:

```
mkdir ".save.$$" &&
  mv ./*[0-9]* ".save.$$/"
  cp ./* /target/directory/ &&
  mv ".save.$$"/* . &&
  rmdir ".save.$$"
```

This will intentionally not copy dot files. If you want those included you would need a more complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if this is the best way, but this works:

```bash
cp $(ls --ignore="*[0-9]*") YOUR_DIR
```

**EDIT:**

(read comment from @StéphaneChazelas why you should not use the first command)

This might work better:

```bash
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -regex '.*[0-9].*' -exec cp {} move \;
```

Comment: It only works with GNU `ls` and if `$IFS` contains the newline characters and none of the file names contain characters of `$IFS` (space tab and newline by default) or start with `-`  or with POSIX-like shells other than zsh contain wildcard characters. It also won't copy files whose name starts with `.` and note that depending on the locale, `[0-9]` may match many more characters than 0123456789

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Every day I am here on `unix stackexchange` and I see you on almost every post^^ Where did you learn so much? It feels like you know every thing about `linux` xD No but for real I really like that you help out people so much. I also learned already so much from you. Just wanted to say **thanks** :)

Comment: Thanks. Beware that `find` is recursive and its `-regex` matches on the full path (and on GNU systems at least fails on file paths that are not entirely made of text, and again `[0-9]` may match more than `[0123456789]`).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'for dir(test => none / \d /, ".", "..") { copy $_, $_ ~ ".bak" };'
```

Raku is a language in the Perl-family of programming languages. The Raku code above creates a `.bak` backup file in the same directory. It uses an interesting operator class/type known as a [*Junction*](https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction). There are four Junction types available in the Raku language: `none`, `one`, `any` and `all`.

```bash
~$ ls
persons.txt places.txt  thx1138.txt 
~$ perl6 -e 'for dir(test => none / \d /, ".", "..") { copy $_, $_ ~ ".bak" };'
~$ ls
persons.txt persons.txt.bak places.txt  places.txt.bak  thx1138.txt
```

Above (specifically) a `none` Junction is given a list of 3 items that removes:

1. file-names containing a `\d` digit (using a Regex-matcher),
2. the `"."` dot directory,
3. the `".."` dot-dot directory.

Once the correct file-names are selected, within the block `$_` (these files) are `copy` copied into a backup file consisting of the file-name followed by`.bak` (single tilde `~` is used to concatenate strings in Raku).

---

*Backup/Copy to a different directory:*

Raku has multiple options for copying and/or backing-up files to a different directory. Know that a `path` consists of a `dirname` and `basename`. At some point you'll probably want to obtain `absolute` paths as opposed to `relative` paths (and `resolve`-ing them). Also, you can ascent through a path using `parent`, and add a directory to the path using `add` (which is a synonym for `child`). See the link below, "Input/Output the Definitive Guide" for tips.

Here's one approach (copy to backup `/Tmp` directory with original filenames intact):

```bash
~$ raku -e 'my $Cwd = $*CWD;  \
            mkdir(my $Tmp = $Cwd.parent.add: "/Tmp/"); \
            for $Cwd.dir(test => none / \d /, ".", "..") { 
              copy $_,  IO::Path($Tmp ~ $_.basename) 
            };'
~$ cd ../Tmp
~$ ls
persons.txt places.txt
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Path
https://docs.raku.org/language/io-guide#Input/Output_the_definitive_guide